# how to convert image sequences to video in R?

Tags: r, ffmpeg

any body know how to convert some photo to video using FFMPEG?
i use this code:

```
ffmpeg --framerate 1 -s 1080x1620 -i pictures/%03d.jpeg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 output.mp4
```

i face this error:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "ffmpeg -r 1"
```

Any body can help me?

Comment: This error message suggests you're running this code in R, but this is not R code. Try running it in a terminal.